# UILocalNotification not working properly

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, swift

This is my code.is there anything that i have to add for the localNotification.? Any suggestions. Thanks in advance. I read lots of local notification tutorials. I have no idea what is missed.

```
var localNotifications : UILocalNotification!

    func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {

        localNotifications  = UILocalNotification()
        localNotifications.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 20)
        localNotifications.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
        localNotifications.alertBody = "Check it out!"
        localNotifications.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        localNotifications.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotifications)
```

}

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {

        println("Alvin Notification recieved")

        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active
        {
            // show alertView

            Utilities.sharedInstance.alertThis("Hello", message: "Hey")
        }
        else if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Background
        {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(localNotifications)
        }
        else if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive
        {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(localNotifications)
        }

        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }
```

Comment: notification is not showing.?

Comment: Yes. It is for iOS 8.

Comment: does it print `Alvin Notification recieved`??

Comment: Is your app in the background

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW25):

> In iOS 8 and later, apps that use either local or remote notifications must register the types of notifications they intend to deliver. The system then gives the user the ability to limit the types of notifications your app displays. The system does not badge icons, display alert messages, or play alert sounds if any of these notification types are not enabled for your app, even if they are specified in the notification payload.

As shown in the guide, the sample code that Apple shows is:

```
    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
             UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
```

Answer (score 2):

The Swift way would be like this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert, categories: nil))
```

update: **Xcode 7 • Swift 2.0**

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert , .Sound, .Badge], categories: nil))
```