# UILocalNotification issue with iOS9

Tags: ios9, uilocalnotification, localnotification

Since iOS9, local notification aren't working properly.
Sometimes users receive the notification, sometimes they just don't. My notifications are repeated daily.
Any idea what might causing the issue? I saw some posts, that there's a bug in iOS9, but I'm not sure that's the reason.

Here's a piece of code:

```
    NSDate *alarmDate = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:DEFAULT_SNOOZE_DURATION * i];  
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];  
    localNotif.fireDate = alarmDate;  
    localNotif.timeZone = nil;          
    localNotif.alertBody = alertBody;  

    localNotif.hasAction = YES;  

    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;  
    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;  
    localNotif.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;  

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif]
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Same problem here, my users are complaining about missed notifications after the IOS9 update.

Comment: It looks like new "iOS optimisation" does not allow firing of subsequent notifications.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I got an app rejection for this very reason. There has been no code change in my project between ios8 to ios9 and it was working in ios8.

Comment: Is there a solution for this problem? I suppose one workaround is to "manually" set additional local notifications rather than use repeatInterval? But we are limited in the number of distinct local notifications we can schedule :-(

Answer (score 5):

write below code in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.

[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
{

    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings
                                                   settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|
                                                   UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}

return YES;
```

}

also write this code in AppDeleagte.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
UIAlertView *notificationAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder"    message:notification.alertBody
                                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

[notificationAlert show];

// Set icon badge number to zero
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

write below code in your ViewController, where you wants to implement your local notification.

forExample : Here I initialise UILocalNotification, and Its Firedate is currentTime and 5seconds Interval Time.

After Fire localNotification it will give alert on Your Screen.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];
notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
notification.alertBody = @"This is local notification!";
notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10;


[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been trying for what feels like an internity to make notifications work for iOS<10.0, seems I was missing `registerUserNotificationSettings`. No mention of it in the [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification), damn Apple!

Answer (score 3):

From the Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide:

> In iOS 8 and later, apps that use either local or remote notifications
>   must register the types of notifications they intend to deliver. The
>   system then gives the user the ability to limit the types of
>   notifications your app displays. The system does not badge icons,
>   display alert messages, or play alert sounds if any of these
>   notification types are not enabled for your app, even if they are
>   specified in the notification payload.

As shown in the guide, the sample code that Apple shows is:

```
 UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
             UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27376475/6219830    by : Naughty_Ottsel

This is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];

    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotification.fireDate = date;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Finally got it!";
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

    return YES;
}
```

I hope that help!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Yan. It worked for me. Can we also customize the notification, as in add action buttons?

Answer (score 0):

if You need it for iOS9 but under swift 3.1:

```
final func registerToGetLocalNotificationsFor_iOS9(){
    let types : UIUserNotificationType = [.sound, .alert /*, .badge*/]
    let mySettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: types, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(mySettings)

}
```

on iOS10 is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

Include the below code in Appdelegate.m

```
if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
{
    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
}
```