# call rest-api whenever app is opened through a push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, usage-statistics

For my statistics dashboard inside the backend i need to call a rest-api via alamofire that informs the backend that the user opened the app through a push notification.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: did you try with **applicationWillEnterForeground** or 
**applicationDidBecomeActive** ?

Comment: but how can i then differentiate if the app was opened manually or through a push notification click? I need to see it in my dashboard if the push is effective.

Comment: " through a push notification click " what does it mean ? please

Comment: did you try with UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate - userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)

Comment: @LucasPalaian where can I place this code? I guess the viewcontrollers can differ regarding the state of the app (cold start, or in background)

Comment: You can set your appdelegate to confrom that protocol. import UserNotifications, then AppDelegate: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate and in class body userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)

Comment: I used it with local notifications, i dont know how works push notifications but i think its the same thing when talking about user interaction

Comment: @LucasPalaian ok i try it at home, in the meantime you can  write a full answer for me to mark as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with local notifications so i will give you an example about what i do. I dont know if its the same way for push notifications.

What i do is to set appdelegate to conform to User Notifications delegate

**1: Import**

```
import UserNotifications
```

**2: Add protocol**

```
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
```

**3: Notification Center Instance**

```
var notificationCenter: UNUserNotificationCenter!
```

**4: Initialize and set delegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notificationCenter.delegate = self

    return true  
}
```

**5: NotificationCenter response**

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

       print("notification pressed") 
}
```

Comment: You can do the same (add noti center delegate) in a separated class but you need to keep it instantiated in appDelegate. Hope it helps!

Comment: great contribution, very detailed! But it must be said that this works only for iOS 10 or higher.

Comment: Ohhh yes yes im sorry :(

Comment: do you know how it looks like in iOS 9?

Comment: i dont know but u can try: func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) in app delegate. Look this question maybe it helps to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901918/uilocalnotification-issue-with-ios9